# Class 'Redis' not found in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, redis

Here i am having issue with importing Redis class. I've already imported this class
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;`.

Redis config in .env file

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

inside `config/database.php`

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

These are all the configuration i used but also i am getting the same issue of `"Class 'Redis' not found, A class import is missing"`.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `predis` Redis client you must install `composer require predis/predis`.

The other, more performant option, is to use the `phpredis` client which requires the `redis` PHP extension. https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown